# Catch with false containsValue(Hashmap)

Tags: java, hashmap, try-catch

I want my program to show an error message if I inputted wrong value in type and value.

The error message works well on type but it does not work on the value. What's wrong with it?

```
Map<String, String> Heart = new HashMap();

Heart.put("A", "Heart");
Heart.put("J", "Heart");
Heart.put("Q", "Heart");
Heart.put("K", "Heart");
Heart.put("2", "Heart");
Heart.put("3", "Heart");
Heart.put("4", "Heart");
Heart.put("5", "Heart");
Heart.put("6", "Heart");
Heart.put("7", "Heart");
Heart.put("8", "Heart");
Heart.put("9", "Heart");
Heart.put("10", "Heart");

System.out.print("Value: ");
val = input.next();
System.out.print("Type: ");
typ = input.next();
if(typ.equals("Heart")){
   if(Heart.containsKey(val)&&Heart.containsValue(typ)){
       System.out.println(val+" of "+typ+" is successfully added.\n");
   }
   if(Heart.containsKey(val)==false){
       try{
         throw new InvalidValueException();
       }
       catch(InvalidValueException e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" 2-10, AJQK.\n");
       }
   }
   else if(Heart.containsValue(typ)==false){
       try{
         throw new InvalidValueException();
       }
       catch(InvalidValueException e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" HDSC\n");
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What exactly you want your program to do?

Comment: if(typ.equals("Heart")){  seems redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same value for all the keys, you should create a `List<String>` of types instead of using `Map`. Then you can just allow user to input type and check whether `List#contains` the type or not.

If it's just an example and you will have different value for each type then,

- You can just `throw` `Exception` with message no need to catch and print message. You can pass message in *constructor*.
- If `type` is value and `val` is `key`, then `typ.equals("Heart")` check is redundant, as you are checking `Heart.containsValue(typ)`.
- So, if your `typ` is not `Heart` you will not able to enter the condition and `if(Heart.containsKey(val)==false){` will never be true if `typ` is not `Heart`.
- You should remove the `if(typ.equals("Heart"))` check.

It's better to follow naming convention start variable name with lowercase.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think List<String> is the best choice since the user needs to input Heart,Spade,Clover, or Diamond. I'll just use if else in duplication of data.